# git clone: Invalid certificate chain

Tags: git, macos, github, ssl-certificate

When I typed `git clone https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git` or any other url in terminal always comes out result like`fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git/': SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain`

I am sure don't have expired certificate issue and I'v already tried to set `git config http.sslVerify` to false.

The os is macOS sierra

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to update git, and/or its underlying ssl system, to a more recent version.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

git config http.sslVerify "false"

in your specific repo to disable SSL certificate checking for that repo only.

Also you can set it globally for all repo

git config --global http.sslVerify false